# Do asymptotic functions have asymptotic definite integrals?

Tags: asymptotics

If $f(x) \sim g(x)$, and
$$
I_f = \int_{0}^{t} f(x)dx
$$ 
and
$$
I_g = \int_{0}^{t} g(x)dx
$$

then does $I_f \sim I_g$ (as $t$ goes to infinity) hold? If not, in what situations does it not hold? How would one go about proving such a relation? Furthermore, what might good sources for further reading be?

Comment: There's a small issue is with your use of variables. I suggest switching the $x$ and $t$ around in your $2$ integral definitions so everything is then consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

You can have
$f(x) \sim g(x)$
and $\int (f(x)-g(x))dx
\to \infty$.

An easy example is
$f(x) = g(x) + \frac1{x}$.

Comment: I see, the discontinuity at 0 causes the integrals to differ. However, if the integrals began at 1 instead of 0, then the primitives would in fact be asymptotic, correct? Edit: in fact, there are cases in which they are, see [here.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+t+to+inf+(integrate+from+1+to+t+x%5E2+dx)%2F(integrate+from+1+to+t+(x%5E2%2B1%2Fx)+dx))

Comment: @trytryagain: Given that your integrals start at 0, the example should perhaps have been $f(x) = g(x) + \frac{1}{x+1}$, or something like that, instead. But the singularity at $x=0$ is just a slight annoyance which is really irrelevant here, the point is that the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t} \, dt$ is divergent. So even if you start integrating at 1, the primitives are not asymptotic.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. However, the error for the integral will be the integral of the error for the function. For example, let's say that you are approximating $f(x)$ using $g(x)$ and the error is $o(x)$. The new error will be $\int x dx = o(\frac{1}{2}x^2)$.